# header css not displayed uniformly through out the site

Tags: css, wordpress

my site is http://www.1seoin.com, its header is but it is not displayed properly on all the pages. For example if you look at home page and the other page like our company, you will see the spacing problem. I am not able to understand why it is happening like this. Please Help

```
Header CSS

.top-div {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      float: left;
      height: 40px;
      width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: You mean the unproportional distance between Home and About Us?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast no. The space between url bar and call us, mail us header, it is varing on other pages

Comment: What are you using to look at your website with? This could be browser specific because I am not seeing it in Safari

Comment: @BuddhistBeast google chrome, firefox

Comment: It is browser specific then. I see it in Firefox and not in Safari. Have you tried replacing px with em, so instead of 40px as your height, it would be 2.5em

Comment: @BuddhistBeast tried 2.5em, but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
.div-1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

On other pages (Our Company is what I tried), the margin-top: -14px screws things up. But it is essential for the index page. You must have typed something extra in the index page, like an extra "enter" or something. Or it could be some extra "enter" in your php file in the header. Try disable as many as not-style-related file links, and then see what is going on.

Comment: i cannot find any "enter" in header file

Comment: is there any other solution with you?

Comment: I guess the best way is to set up different attributes for .div-1. For example, keep the margin-top: -14px for index, but get rid of them on the other pages. You can set up separate css for this, or use JavaScript.